# How to use the ECMAScript 6 Unicode code point escapes?

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-6, utf-16

I have [this](https://codepoints.net/U+20BB5) Unicode character that I want to display using the new Unicode Point Escapes (i.e.e where someone uses `'\u{Code Point Here}'`

However, I must be doing something wrong because doing

`console.log('\u{134069}');`

returns:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined Unicode code-point`

But using

`console.log('\ud842\udfb5')`

returns the (correct)

How can I use the code point escape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode escape sequences in Javascript use hexadecimal digits to represent codepoints (which makes sense, given they are very typically represented this way). You have tried to use `134069`, which, based on the surrogate pair you've supplied, is actually the decimal representation of the codepoint you're wanting to print. You'll need use hex equivalent instead, e.g. `\u{20BB5}` in ES6.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use HEX numbers in unicode sequence, as you have already seen. However, there's no need to use character escapes, just write or copy/paste your characters into the string, save it as utf-8 and you're going.
Javascript is today unicode (well most of JavaScript is).

Answer (score 0):

`\u{...}` is a [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) and above Unicode escape sequences, and `\u1234` is a [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)-only escape sequences. The generalized `\u{...}` format is a new feature of ES6. Support for them will be entirely dependent on your target JS environments, or if you are using a transpiler.